# Kickstart "Unable to download kickstart file. Check parameter"

Tags: centos, virtualization, kickstart, syslinux

So I'm using 2 VMs (CentOS 6.0), one acting as a build server, the other is a new server I'm trying to build with a kickstart.

When I start the VM for the new server (with the build server already running), It says "retrieving /default.ks", but doesn't go past 0%. It then brings me to a prompt that says "Unable to download the kickstart file. Please modify the kickstart parameter below" (`http://10.1.1.20/Kickstart/default.ks`).

I've got httpd running fine (access_log is empty and error_log doesn't seem to say anything), the pxelinux configuration points to the right file, and dhcp is running fine (I can ping the new machine from the build server).

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you wget that URL from the build server itself?

Comment: Can you browse to: http://10.1.1.20/Kickstart/default.ks ?

Comment: Here's my pxelinux config file `http://pastebin.com/PQsK0JuZ`

Comment: wget works when I use it on the server itself.